# Can someone explain MQSeries file based JNDI for remote client JMS access

Tags: jms, jndi, ibm-mq

I've been searching extensively for a description of how to set up JMS access from a remote client to a file based JNDI MQ Series provider without success.

My JMS client works Ok on the same Linux machine as my MQSeries 7.5 server using file based JNDI.

How does one set up a remote client to use file based JNDI? Is it even possible or must one use LDAP?

I've seen hints that one should be able to have a remote client but nothing very clear.

I'm using Spring JMSTemplate which uses a provider url. On the same machine my Tomcat context.xml file uses a file: fileName url which, as I say, works ok collocated with the MQSeries server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assuming that there was more than there is to file based JNDI. All it is is reading a property file. Using the "file"" url format allows you to read remote files.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem.  If you are using a File based JNDI then you just need to add a QCF that contains the appropriate information for the remote queue manager.  i.e. hostname, port # and channel name

```
DEFINE QCF(myQCF) QMANAGER(MQWT1) CHANNEL(TEST.CHL) HOSTNAME(22.22.22.22) PORT(1414) TRANSPORT(CLIENT) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
```

Comment: Thanks but I've got a jms connection factory setup with MQ Explorer with those parameters set and it's not working. Do I need to have a binding file on the client or anything else?

Comment: Well Ya.  Copy the bindings file to the client server and in the application code set the Context.PROVIDER_URL to the path of bindings file.

Comment: Tried that without success.